# lapply and colnames produces invalid 'y' type in 'x && y' error

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of data.frames.  I want to take a character vector and use its values as the column names in all of the data.frames in the list.  When I try to use `lapply` for this, I get the following error:

`Error in is.data.frame(x) && do.NULL : invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'`

Here is a reproducible example:

```
x = 1:5
y = 6:10
z = 11:15
newnames = c("Var1", "Var2")
dflist = list("df1" = cbind.data.frame(x,y), "df2" = cbind.data.frame(x,z))
str(dflist)
lapply(dflist, colnames, newnames)
```

Answer (score 3):

Discovered the solution while making the reproducible example.  The problem is that `colnames` is not the same as `colnames<-`.  The code in the question above attempts to *retrieve* the column names from each member of dflist, and passes the vector of column names as an additional, unnecessary argument.  The appropriate last line for the reproducible example is as follows:

```
lapply(dflist, `colnames<-`, newnames)
```

Comment: Or another option is `lapply(dflist, setNames, newnames)`